# magento 2 and varnish 5.2

Tags: magento2, varnish

I installed varnish 5.2 and Magento 2.3.2 after that I check the varnish header and it worked very well but after move default.vlc it does not work.
this is my default.vlc

https://pastebin.com/Bz7WA1RB

where I am going wrong?

Comment: this answer saved my time
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252739/magento-2-facing-issue-in-varnish-configuration

Comment: Where you successful in getting magento2 & varnish 5.2 work perfectly? I am planning to do same.

Answer (score 0):

can you try the default.vcl without `.probe{....}` in `backend default {` if it is the issue, varnish health check failed.

Comment: hi sir ... it did not work...can you explain what happens with your change
my default.vcl was created by Magento