# Magento2 need to check if varnish cache is applied or not

Tags: magento2, varnish

How can I verify whether my Varnish Cache is properly configured or not.

Here are the things that appeared

1. page_cache is not getting regenerated
2. Site speed as per Google page speed is improved

My site is set on http://x.x.x.x & is redirected to https://x.x.xx.x

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2020 13:59:25 GMT
Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2020 13:59:25 GMT
< Server: Apache
Server: Apache
< Pragma: cache
Pragma: cache
< Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
< Expires: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 13:59:26 GMT
Expires: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 13:59:26 GMT
< X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,cat_c,cat_c_38,cat_c_20,cat_c_41,cat_c_3,cat_c_58,cat_c_39,cms_b_,cms_b_31,cms_b_em0144-fashion-area-footer-inner-payment,cms_b_60,cms_b_em0144-jewelry-area-footer01-information-footer07,cms_b_48,cms_b_em0144-jewerly-main-slideshow,cms_b_52,cms_b_em0144-jewelry-top-banners,cms_b_54,cms_b_em0144-jewelry-area-main01-new-arrivals-grid12,cms_p_7
X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,cat_c,cat_c_38,cat_c_20,cat_c_41,cat_c_3,cat_c_58,cat_c_39,cms_b_,cms_b_31,cms_b_em0144-fashion-area-footer-inner-payment,cms_b_60,cms_b_em0144-jewelry-area-footer01-information-footer07,cms_b_48,cms_b_em0144-jewerly-main-slideshow,cms_b_52,cms_b_em0144-jewelry-top-banners,cms_b_54,cms_b_em0144-jewelry-area-main01-new-arrivals-grid12,cms_p_7
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3fe21bcb4a2d0cd17f4304ff6c6346ca; expires=Wed, 22-Jul-2020 14:59:26 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=monogramshop.com.au; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3fe21bcb4a2d0cd17f4304ff6c6346ca; expires=Wed, 22-Jul-2020 14:59:26 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=monogramshop.com.au; secure; HttpOnly
< Content-Length: 101554
Content-Length: 101554
< Vary: User-Agent
Vary: User-Agent
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
< Cache-Control: max-age=86400, private, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, private, must-revalidate
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The above is output of curl -I -v --location-trusted 'https://x.x.x/'

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2020 14:02:19 GMT
Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2020 14:02:19 GMT
< Last-Modified: Mon, 07 Oct 2019 08:45:22 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 07 Oct 2019 08:45:22 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: text/html
Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Encoding: gzip
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: -1
Expires: -1
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< Via: HTTP/1.1 forward.http.proxy:3128
Via: HTTP/1.1 forward.http.proxy:3128
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
```

The above is output of curl -I -v --location-trusted 'http://x.x.x/'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento's *VCL file* will strip off the `X-Varnish` header, which indicates whether or not Varnish is used.

By removing `unset resp.http.X-Varnish;` from the `sub vcl_deliver` subroutine, the header will reapper.

If your HTTP response then contains an `X-Varnish` response header, you know it was served through Varnish.

Enabling Magento's debug mode will also add some extra debug headers to your HTTP responses, which will help you understand whether or not the response was a *cache hit* or a *cache miss*.

Comment: Hello @Thijs thanks for your comments. I am able to see X-Varnish but X-Magento-Cache-Debug is yet not available. Can you please advice some thing on this?

Comment: From what I see in Magento's VCL file, is that Magento will send a `X-Magento-Debug` header when debug mode is enabled. This is something you should set in your Magento admin panel. You might want to flush the cache to make sure it doesn't conflict with anything else.

Comment: The frontend header I am getting X-Magento-Debug as 1. Regarding  X-Magento-Cache-Debug isn't it true that it will display only if site is HTTP as file says resp.http.X-Magento-Debug

Comment: if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

Comment: @Arjun Could you please add your full (redacted) VCL file to your original question? It will be easier to understand what's going on. I've used https://gist.github.com/hummer2k/6f32c489937f539f10ce for inspiration, but that might not be the same one you're using.

Comment: Here is my details https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317941/magento2-3-2-varnish-5-cache-issue

Comment: Based on https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html#change-to-developer-mode, I assume you need to activate *developer mode* to see the hit/miss headers.